# In "The Prisoner of Azkaban" book Hermione slapped Draco. But in the movie did she really just slap him? Or did she punch him?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm asking for differences in the Book vs. The Movie.

Answer (score 3):

The [script](https://www.gazette-du-sorcier.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/pdf_Azkabanscript.pdf) has her **punching** him in the face.

> Hermione nods, then -- SMACK! -- quick as lightning,  **lands a looping
> right to Malfoy's jaw, putting him flat  on his back.** Stunned, he
> leaps to his feet and runs,  Crabbe and Goyle huffing and puffing
> behind.

Harry also then describes it as a punch in a later scene.

> **HARRY:** (in admiration) *Good punch.*

This seems to be borne out by Emma Watson's stunt double's description of the scene.

> It was probably cut because **my punch was really rubbish and so not
> convincing so they just kept in Emma's.** I am a really non-athletic
> person. **I have never thrown a punch before in my life and the team
> told me just go for it so you are like 'oh okay'.** It is such a great
> scene, isn't it. I filmed the scene as well and so did Emma, so that
> happens all the time, we both film a scene and they just edit it
> together. Our hands did not connect with his face it was more like a
> pass to him and he did the reaction.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter: Emma Watson's Double Recalls Filming Draco Punch Scene](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-emma-watson-double-draco-punch-scene/)</sup></sub>

And Tom Felton's description of the scene. Note that he'd read the book and was aware that it was supposed to be a slap [until it got re-written](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/emma-watson-slapped-harry-potter-castmate-tom-felton-off-camera.html/).

> **What was it like being punched by Emma Watson?**
>
> *Uh, pretty hardcore. **She’s got a mean right hook, that girl. It was originally a slap I think, so I said, "Let’s test it out now. Give me
> a slap and try to work on it," meaning give me a screen slap, a fake
> slap. But she actually smacked me on the face pretty hard,** and I
> walked away from that rather listening impaired with my tail tucked
> between my legs.*
>
> [image: Hermione Granger (Emma Watson) slapping Draco Malfoy (Tom Felton) in the movie "The Prisoner of Azkaban"]

Comment: "But she actually smacked me on the face pretty hard" well that's just method acting ‍♂️